# Renaming and deleting a music playlist in Android 10+

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to update my old music player to support Android 10 and 11 (and 12 soon)

My code to rename and delete a playlist broke due to changes in security I guess ?? Here is what used to work :

```
private fun renamePlaylist(resolver: ContentResolver, playlist: Playlist, newName: String) {

    val uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val selection = "${MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID}=${playlist.id}"

    val c = ContentValues()
    c.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME, newName)

    resolver.update(uri, c, selection, null)

}
```

and

```
fun deletePlaylist(resolver: ContentResolver, id: Long) {

    val uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val selection = "${MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID}=$id"

    resolver.delete(uri, selection, null)

}
```

I have tested again on a Android 9 device and it works perfectly. Now I have this error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Movement of content://media/external/audio/playlists which isn't part of well-defined collection not allowed

After digging the Android source code it looks like my URI is of type AUDIO_PLAYLISTS and it expects a type AUDIO_PLAYLISTS_ID. So i tried to cheat and append the playlist id to the URI to match the expected type. Now it doesn't crash but the playlist is not deleted either, nothing happens

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use  the uri from`MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)` for Q and above and `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` for below Q

This is because of the recent scoped storage changes

Comment: Using MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY is not solving the problem